# One bathroom faucet, cold water only, unless I run multiple faucets?

Tags: faucet, hot-water

I have a 5 year old home in NC. In the master bath, I have a his-hers dual sink with two handled Delta faucets.

One faucet is broken and can only provide cold water from both sides.  If I run hot water from another faucet, I will get hot water fairly quickly.  If I open both faucets, I will get hot water from both faucets.  If I close the perfectly working faucet, the broken faucet will return to only cold water.

I have shut off the cold water supply to the broken faucet and confirmed that no water will come from the cold side.  I did the same with the hot water supply and confirmed that no water comes from the hot side.

I have an inline water heater.

Everywhere else is functioning normally.

As it stands, if I want hot water, I need to run two faucets.

Where should I start looking?

Comment: Why not replace the broken faucet?

Comment: The faucet is not broken, but as is it restricts the flow to below the minimum required for the tankless water heater to come on.  The simplest remedy is to modify the flow restrictor in the faucet to increase the flow enough to be above the minimum.

Comment: Other possibility is that the supply line to this faucet is restricting the flow. Does thus house have PEX piping? Does the faucet have a separate supply line which connects to a manifold with a valve there? If so, make sure the valve at the manifold is fully open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inline water heater (tankless WH) requires a minimum flow rate to turn on. The faucet you are using has a flow rate below the minimum. When you run the other faucet the combined  flow is enough to be above the minimum.

If you would remove the aerator on the end of the faucet, this would probably increase the flow rate above the minimum. You could probably enlarge the orifice in the flow restrictor in the aerator to allow reinstalling it and have the water heater turn on.

Some tankless WHs allow the minimum turn on flow rate to be adjusted. Sometimes people have trouble with a low flow shower head running cold water from the hot supply if no other hot water is being used at the same time.

Comment: Fixed!  I can't believe this was the reason!  Genius!  Thanks Jim for taking the time to answer me!